# Location Element not parsed from Stack Overflow Jobs RSS feed

Tags: ruby, rss

I am trying to parse the RSS feed from a Stack Overflow Jobs search ([URL](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?q=%5Bruby%5D&l=New%20York%2C%20NY%2C%20United%20States&d=20&u=Miles)) using the built in Ruby RSS parser.  For some reason I cannot access the Location element from the feed.

It crashes with

```
 undefined method `location' for #<RSS::Rss::Channel::Item:0x000000020db720> (NoMethodError)
```

I am able to get the other elements (title, description, link, etc.) but not the location

Code

```
require 'rss'
require 'open-uri'

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?q=%5bruby%5d&l=New+York%2c+NY%2c+United+States&d=20&u=Miles"
open(url) do |rss|
    feed = RSS::Parser.parse(rss)
    puts "Title: #{feed.channel.title}"
    feed.items.each do |item|
        puts item.title
        puts item.location
    end
end
```

How do I get this location value?

[image: screenshot of formatted xml]

Comment: I copy/paste the URL in Google Chrome and I can't see the `location` attribute. are you sure that such URL is the correct one? if so, please add and screenshot of the `location` attribute you're looking for from the URL.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave I added a screenshot and I have done a little reading and I thing I meant element instead of attribute. Either way I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the location element has a namespace (`xmlns` attribute). I have not been able to find anything on how to use namespaces in the Ruby RSS model but using [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org) you can define custom namespaces and parse out the location attribute with the XPath ([nokogiri docs](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#namespaces)).

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

# Open the URL with Nokogiri XML parser
xml = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?q=%5Bruby%5D&l=New%20York%2C%20NY%2C%20United%20States&d=20&u=Miles"))

# xml.xpath('XPath', 'custom_namespace' => "http://namespace/url")
puts xml.xpath('//rss/channel/item/so:location', 'so' => 'http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/')
```